# How to retrieve Mongo query string from FindIterable (mongo java driver)

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, driver

Is there a way to simply retrieve the query string that MongoDB java driver does?
For example:

```
filter = eq("field","value");

FindIterable<BasicDBObject> find = collection.find(filter).projection(fields(include("field"), excludeId()));
```

When iterating, this should invoke the query :

```
db.collection.find({"field":"value"},{"field":1, "_id":0})
```

which will be split in batches, the first of which will be of 101 elements and next ones of max 16MB (but I don't really care about this. I just need the initial query).
Is there a way to retrieve this string from the FindIterable or other objects of mongodb java driver?

I read elsewhere of people who were suggesting to do it from logging. I need the query string at runtime cause I have to use it.

Comment: What do you mean by query string here?

Comment: db.collection.find({"field":"value"},{"field":1, "_id":0}), or also find({"field":"value"},{"field":1, "_id":0}). The query that I'd normally see on system.profile collection

Comment: How do you want to use this query at runtime?

Comment: I need to send it to a serverless. The logic of building up the filter must be done on mongo java driver side, cause it's complex. But then, instead of iterating in java and run the query, I just need the so built query to send it to a serverless

Comment: FindIterable would have a cursor object. In java, it is `MongoCursor`. You cannot get query from it. You need to get the string representation of the query, before getting the result from `find` command and use it further.

Comment: yeah, that's what I'm asking here. How to retrieve the query string. I wrote FindIterable but could be anything. I just need a way to retrieve the query

Comment: There are ways, but you need to combine multiple strings. Not a straightforward way

Comment: The query filter, projection, sort criteria, etc., can be got from the MongoDB server log. I dont know if the information will be there with default log levels. But, with a higher log level you can see the query filter, projection info. See the commands `db.getLogComponents()` and `db.setLogLevel()`. An example, with `db.setLogLevel(4, "query")`, I can see the server log's QUERY component with the details `ns: test.bks query: { author: "Mark Twain" } sort: {} projection: { title: 1, _id: 0 }`. The query code I ran was using Java Driver  v3.12 and MongoDB server v4.2.8.

Comment: The `filter` variable has the query - you just want it a JSON `{"field":"value"}`?

Comment: yeah, that would be something already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with the Java Driver v4.2 and MongoDB v4.2.8. You can get the filter and projection from the `Bson` as JSON string values.

```
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = client.getDatabase("test").getCollection("books");
    Bson filter = eq("author", "Mark Twain");
    String filterJson = filter.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, Bson.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY).toJson();
    System.out.println(filterJson);    // {"author": "Mark Twain"}
    Bson projectn = fields(include("title"), excludeId());
    String projectJson = projectn.toBsonDocument(Document.class, Bson.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY).toJson();
    System.out.println(projectJson);    // {"title": 1, "_id": 0}
    coll.find(filter).projection(projectn);
```

Comment: I've used this example to create a builder that builds up the final string. So, this helped me! thanks